# Orbeon - Form Runner - Access Control documentation needs some cleanup?

Tags: orbeon

In a couple of places [Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Setup](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Setup) says

> configure `form-builder-permissions.xml` as described above

But it appears that this documentation has been moved to another page. Should it be referring to [Form Builder permissions](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Editing-Forms#form-builder-permissions)?

The first paragraph on [Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Setup](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Setup) also says:

> Form Runner uses the username, group, and roles to control who can access Form 
>   Builder and the forms you create with Form Builder (see the two sections above 
>   for more details on how those are setup).

There are no sections above on that page. I think it is referring to [Editing Forms](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Editing-Forms) and [Deployed Forms](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Deployed-Forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmh… I removed that sentence from the documentation, as it doesn't seem to belong there. There are two parts you might want setup access control for: Form Builder and the forms you've deployed. The former is documented in [Access Control ~ Editing Forms](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Editing-Forms), the latter in [Access Control ~ Deployed Forms](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Deployed-Forms). And in both cases, you need to do some initial setup, documented in [Access Control ~ Setup](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Access-Control-~-Setup).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the page to link to Editing Forms and Deployed Forms instead of saying "see the two sections above" since those sections are on a different page. The Header-driven method section had the same sentence about form-builder-permissions.xml that didn't fit so I removed that.